# d3.js tree - How to set Y depth of a specific level?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In d3.js tree code, there is the following which sets the y depth for all child levels/nodes:

```
  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.y = d.depth * 220;
  });
```

How can I set the Y depth of a specific level in the hierarchy, e.g. the 3rd level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you refer to [this code](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/8375092)
Simple example for the third level.

```
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 (d.depth === 1) ? d.y = d.depth * 100: d.y = d.depth * 300; 
});
```

It display this https://jsfiddle.net/0rv8z276/

You can use a switch to set for different level, or maybe use an array or a hashmap with the key associated to the level and depth as the value.

Comment: That is only working for one node/child on the level.  How to have all children nodes at the same set distance for a level?

Comment: Well I changed it. But personally I think you need to try a bit to find your solution yourself.
I mean, I only did a `console.log(d,i)`, instantly saw that depth is what interest you here and swap it with i. You should try yourself before asking those kind of thing

Comment: Yes, you are correct, I should have investigated more.  Too rushed.

Comment: No problem, glad to help and we're all here for that. It was just a reminder